# Reflection : Getting members from inherited interface, but not from inherited class

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection

I believe I've got an interesting question there, since I couldn't find a clue about that during my research.

```
public interface IClass
{
    int i { get; set; }
}

public class A
{
    int j { get; set; }
}

public class B : A, IClass
{
    string property { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to know if it is possible, using Reflection, to get all the inherited members of my class B and from the inherited interface IClass, but without the property from the inherited class A.

I've tried using BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly, but this always gets all the inherited members, when I only desire to get the ones from the Interface.

Any ideas, please ?

--
Arjune

**EDIT** : I intend to get interface inherited properties, with a generic class T.
Here is what I tried which worked, thanks to your answers :

```
List<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Where(x => x.DeclaringType != typeof(T).BaseType).ToList();
```

Besides the properties of B, this allowed me to get the properties from IClass but not the ones from class A. LINQ and the use of DeclaringType was the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go about this in a number of ways, depending on your exact aim.

One idea is to get all properties normally then filter out those coming from class `A` using `DeclaringType`, e.g.

```
var typeOfA = typeof(A);
var notFromA = allMembers.Where(
    p => p.DeclaringType != typeOfA && !p.DeclaringType.IsSubclassOf(typeOfA));
```

Or of course you can simply ignore the base class completely and get only the members coming from implemented interfaces, e.g.

```
var members = typeof(B).GetInterfaces().SelectMany(i => i.GetMembers());
```

This will give you all members of `B` that are implementations of interface members -- not necessarily all of B's declared members, and it will include interface members that `A` has implemented.

In general the correct way to do this depends on the exact requirements, but I feel the question is not precise enough in its current form.

Comment: Wont this add an unnecessary dependency because of `typeof(A)`?

Comment: It does if you are trying to make a method that could handle any scenario.  With this mechanism you'd need to know the full class hierarchy already.

Comment: @ppittle: Depends. If you *literally* want "members not coming from `A`" then you have to take a dependency on `A`. If you don't mean it literally then you can do without.

Comment: Ok, fair point.  But I think @Glad is looking to filter out any class, not specifically `A`.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific.
Yes, I want to get those inherited properties from a generic class T.
I just wanted to know if it was possible to distinguish interface inherited properties from class inherited properties.

Comment: @Glad: It is possible, but keep in mind that you don't *inherit* properties from interfaces; you just *acquire the obligation to implement them*. Each property declared in an interface will be inherited by one of your ancestor classes as far as reflection is concerned. It's your own job to determine if these properties are "inherited from interfaces" or "just declared on the spot".

Comment: True. It would have been more accurate to consider inherited properties (from inherited class) _and_ mandatory properties (from interface) as non-declared properties, maybe ?

Since the BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly attribute won't get those properties.

Anyway, thank you Jon ! your answer was helpful enough and I've got what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If given a type `T` you want to get all inherited members from an interface, you can try this:

```
public static IEnumerable<MemberInfo> GetAllInterfaceMembers(this Type t){
     return t.GetInterfaces().SelectMany(x => x.GetMembers());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var members = type.GetMembers(flags).Concat(
    type.GetInterfaces().SelectMany(x => x.GetMembers(flags))).ToList();
```

(where `flags` is your chosen `BindingFlags` options, that **must** include `DeclaredOnly`)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var allMembers = myType.GetMembers()
    .Union(myType.GetInterfaces()
    .SelectMany(i => i.GetMembers())
```